Is there a way of getting the mailutils package to work in windows?
I am compiling Emacs from source on Windows using MSYS2 on the environment UCRT64. When compiling emacs there is a message about emacs using as standard during the build process (at least in Windows) the POP package for mail handling which apparently uses insecure connections, it then suggests putting --without-pop on the ./configure command to remove this source of insecurity.
I don't know if I would like to use emacs for reading emails, but I would like to build emacs to at least have the capability of such. I know that for secure email retrieval in Linux emacs uses the GNU Mailutils package, but there does not seem to be a pre-build mailutils package for UCRT (or for any other environment) on the MSYS2 repository.
Is it impossible to simply build the mailutils package from source in windows using the GNU utilities available in the URCT environment of MSYS2? Or would the build process be so long and depend on so many other non-pre-build packages that it would be unfeasible in practice?
It would be no problem for me if the build process is somewhat long, as long as it didn't take more than 3 days to complete the build of the mailutils package in URCT. I didn't try this yet because I could not find any posts about this, and there is the possibility of mailutils using explicitly Linux system calls or otherwise incompatible code for Windows in the source code itself, kind of like how chmod doesn't work in MSYS2.

This is not really a question about Emacs, but for mailutils. You should probably ask on their mailing list. As I am familiar with, mailutils do not compile natively on Windows. Cygwin can build it, but I don't know about MSYS2, you will have to ask on their GH. Should be able since they are a Cygwin fork. You should be able to get mailutils up and running in WSL. I also suggest to use MINGW runtime to compile Emacs, because UCRT runtime is not supported yet, and the patch provided by MSYS2 folk to make it work is really just hiding the problem. Emacs will crash often in UCRT runtime.

Are you quite sure about this instability with Emacs compiled with UCRT runtime? As I understand UCRT is made to be a windows native port of the base utilities of Linux in Windows, meaning that it probably is more performant and less bloated than MINGW, if possible I would like to use UCRT, but if what you are telling is true then I will use MINGW. Can you just provide a source for your assertion that UCRT is just being haphazardly patched by MSYS2 and that this results in instabilities? I have never seen any warnings anywhere about this.

Both mingw and ucrt  runtimes are "Windows native". UCRT is a newer Microsoft C runtime and is meant to be "universal" and work on all versions of Windows. The [patch by msys2 folks[(https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-emacs/001-ucrt.patch) just ignores errors as seen in the source code. I have experienced a lot of crashes, usually when using Dired. There is also a post about it on the mailing list, you are free to search it yourself as well as to test UCRT yourself. I wouldn't use it until emacs devs declare UCRT as a supported runtime officially.
